# Toggle row color red and table color white on click with pure javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to duplicate the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2pJN/) in pure javascript without relying on jquery or other methods.

```js
$('table tr').each(function(a,b){
    $(b).click(function(){
        $('table tr').css('background','#ffffff');
        $(this).css('background','#ff0000');   
    });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first click highlights a row, the second click highlights the next selected row and removes the highlight from the previous row. Also, I've tried implementing this code in my work but it wouldn't work at all and provides 0 error messages to give me a clue as to what is going on. Copy/pasting this fiddle into a new one does not reproduce the results and this seems to be a common theme while trying to track down an answer to this problem. I've searched all over stackoverflow and haven't been able to find a working solution that relies only on css, javascript, and/or html.

Comment: Can you provide your attempt at a non-jQuery solution, and maybe we can point out what's wrong with it?

Comment: Here's my current attempt, it's a bit of mess after trying out several different options: https://jsfiddle.net/M4V3R1C8/tbk389to/

Comment: The updated attempt works well enough in jsfiddle and can be copy/pasted to new instances without breaking. Unfortunately the issue seems to be coming from it's integration in the larger development process. rip.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[].forEach.call` to iterate `tr` elements. Use of [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is needed as [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) does not return `Array`.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table tr'),
  function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table tr'), function(el) {
        el.style.background = '#fff';
      });
      this.style.background = '#f00'
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    <th>Column4</th>
    <th>Column5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OP wants  pure javascript without relying on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/M4V3R1C8/7L2typ5t/1/ 
This script allows you to do exactly what I was looking for. The only downside is that you cannot activate the top row. Also, I can't seem to change the .selected name as it will stop working. Good enough for now, onto the next problem.

```
function selected(){
    var index,
      table = document.getElementById("dps");
  for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
        if(typeof index !== "undefined"){
          table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
      }
      console.log(typeof index);
      index = this.rowIndex;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
      console.log(typeof index);
    };
  }
}
selected();
```